# Why i can't take a screenshot with Puppeteer for this website https://www.leptitpinard.fr

Tags: puppeteer

### I usur this code to do a screenshot :

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
try {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: 'new' });
const page = await browser.newPage();

```
    await page.goto('https://www.leptitpinard.fr', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
    await browser.close();
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during capture:', error);
}
```

}

### run();

**I make screenshots without problem for all sites except this one : **https://www.leptitpinard.fr****

**I have this error :**
root@vps-0134553348d1:/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api# node test1.js
/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/assert.js:28
throw new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot extract value when objectId is given
at assert (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/assert.js:28:15)
at valueFromRemoteObject (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:239:28)
at createClientError (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:122:16)
at CDPPage._CDPPage_handleException (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:894:94)
at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:186:100
at /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:248
at Array.map ()
at Object.emit (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/third_party/mitt/index.js:3:232)
at CDPSessionImpl.emit (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:87:22)
at CDPSessionImpl._onMessage (/var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.fr/httpdocs/api/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:441:18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is a bug https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/10224 on that specific version.

I have tested your code on v20.4.0 and its working fine.